# PHP Session_start() throws Server error 500 for some users only

Tags: php, iis, server

I manage a small webserver for work, and everything has been working perfectly so far.

Then yesterday, alot of users were getting a Server error 500, even though i did not change a single line of code.

I have narrowed it down to the line that says `<?php Session_start(); ?>`
But only for some users, my user works fine but my colleague is getting a server error.

I saw somewhere that the Session-handler should be set to files, and it still is so i know that, that is not the problem.

Can anyone think where i should look or do you need the logs or something?

Thank you

***EDIT:***

**IIS Log File:**

For Other users:
2020-02-04 11:00:52 XXX xx.xx.xxx.x GET /QMT/ 80 - xx.xx.xx.x HTTP/1.1 XXX 401
2020-02-04 11:00:52 XXX xx.xx.xxx.x GET /QMT/ 80 Dom\User1 xx.xxx.xx.x HTTP/1.1 XXX 500
2020-02-04 11:01:38 XXX xx.xx.xxx.x GET / 80 - xx.xx.x.xx HTTP/1.1 XXX 401
2020-02-04 11:01:38 XXX xx.xx.xxx.x GET / 80 Dom\User2 xx.xx.x.xx HTTP/1.1 XXX 500

**This is what it looks like for my user:**

2020-02-04 07:58:11 XXX xx.xx.xxx.x GET /Jobs/log.php 80 Dom\Me xx.xx.xxx.x HTTP/1.1 XXX 200
2020-02-04 07:58:11 XXX xx.xx.xxx.x GET /Jobs/jobs.php 80 Dom\Me xx.xx.xxx.x HTTP/1.1 XXX 200
2020-02-04 07:58:11 XXX xx.xx.xxx.x GET /Jobs/getData.php 80 Dom\Me xx.xx.xxx.x HTTP/1.1 XXX 200

Comment: please check apache2 error log

Comment: Check Jobs/log.php, Jobs/jobs.php, Jobs/getData.php files, and enable error reporting from php.ini `display_errors = on` than add this to top of your php files `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` will give you correct errors. see debuging step by step here :https://www.cloudways.com/blog/php-debug/

Answer (score 1):

The 500 Internal Server Error is a very general HTTP status code that means something has gone wrong on the web site's server but the server could not be more specific on what the exact problem is.

**Resolution Possibilities**

The 500 Internal Server Error is a "server-side" error, meaning the problem is not with your PC or Internet connection but instead is a problem with the web site's server.
Even though the issue is not yours to troubleshoot or resolve, there are a few things you can do:

1. Retry the web page by clicking the refresh/reload button or trying the URL from the address bar again.
   Even though the 500 Internal Server Error is reporting a general error on the web site's servers and not your computer, the server error may only be temporary. Trying the page again will often be successful.
2. Come back later. 
   The 500 Internal Server Error message is one of the most common error message seen when checking out during an online purchase so sales are often disrupted. 
   This is usually a great incentive to resolve the issue very quickly.
3. Try Clearing your cache and browser history. 
   It could be possible that the page you are seeing is a cached version, so after the cache is cleared it will go away.

> 4. You can check the error log button in cPanel under the logs section to see what errors are being given if you have cPanel hosting, or check error_log file.

.

Sometimes 500 errors can be due to syntax errors in a .htaccess file or other things you may be able to quickly fix yourself.

Comment: This has persisted all day today and yesterday, we tried refreshing multiple times to no avail. I tried from a new computer and its the same.

Comment: What error_log file says ? your option 4. is highlighted in answer, please try that and edit your question, give people something to think about :)

Comment: Updated the question with a snippet of the log files.

Answer (score -1):

I just had this same problem, and it seems the problem was that my PHP log file had grown to over 36 GB in size.  I deleted the log file and the problem went away.